# Controller instantiation in Yii framework by directory and namespace

Tags: php, yii, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

Yii framework supports modules and also subdirectories in controllers directory, so path to some specific action could be

- `/index.php?r=module/controller/action` or
- `/index.php?r=subdirectoryInControllerDir/controller/action`.

My goal here is to have multiple subdirectories in the controllers directory. Inside these folders I would create controllers with the same names as parent ones using namespaces.

However if I write

```
namespace mynamespace;
class MyController extends \MyController {
}
```

Yii would load `MyController` instead of `mynamespace\MyController;`

Any suggestions here?

Comment: I think this would be better asked in Stack Overflow. If so I can return the bounty and migrate the question. Just let me know if you agree.

Comment: This looks like SO material indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yii uses an intuitive naming convention for namespaces, which starts from \application and must follow the physical directory structure, like the built-in autoload config.
If your base MyController class is in protected/controllers/, then it should use `namespace application\controllers;`

```
<?php
namespace application\controllers;
class MyController extends \CController
{
    // actions
}
```

and the child MyController in protected/controllers/subdir/

```
<?php
namespace application\controllers\subdir;
class MyController extends \application\controllers\MyController
{
    // actions
}
```

To make a request like "subdir/my" work, you need to add the following code to `CWebApplication::createController()` (or inherit it in a subclass) right after the class file is included:

```
    if(!class_exists($className,false))
        require($classFile);
+   if(!class_exists($className,false))
+       $className = '\\application\\controllers\\' . str_replace('/', '\\', $controllerID . $className);
    if(class_exists($className,false) && is_subclass_of($className,'CController'))
    {
        $id[0]=strtolower($id[0]);
        return array(
            new $className($controllerID.$id,$owner===$this?null:$owner),
            $this->parseActionParams($route),
        );
    }
```

If you have set `controllerNameSpace` of `CWebApplication` you can also use that value instead of hardcoding `\\application\\controllers\\`.